# Error while upgade

Tags: upgrade

While upgrading Ubuntu 12.10 by terminal using `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtinyxml-dev : Depends: libtinyxml (= 2.6.2-2~ppa1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I have tried all ways but could not solve the problem. Here is the result of appropriate commands.
I tried `sudo apt-cache search libtinyxml` and result was:

```
root@nadirhajiyev:/home/nadirhajiyev# sudo apt-cache search libtinyxml
libtinyxml-dev - TinyXml library - header and static library
libtinyxml-doc - TinyXml library - documentation files
libtinyxml2-0.0.0 - C++ XML parsing library
libtinyxml2-dev - TinyXML2 library - header and static library
libtinyxml2.6.2 - C++ XML parsing library
libtinyxml2.6.2-dbg - TinyXml library - debug files
libtinyxml2.5.3 - dummy transitional package from libtinyxml2.5.3 to libtinyxml
libtinyxml2.5.3-dbg - dummy transitional package from libtinyxml2.5.3-dbg to libtinyxml-dbg
libtinyxml - C++ XML parsing library
libtinyxml-dbg - TinyXml library - debug files
```

Then `apt-get install -y libtinyxml libtinyxml-dev`:

```
root@nadirhajiyev:/home/nadirhajiyev# apt-get install -y libtinyxml libtinyxml-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libtinyxml-dev is already the newest version.
libtinyxml-dev set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  erlang-base erlang-crypto erlang-syntax-tools libqt4-webkit:i386 libsctp1 linux-headers-3.5.0-17 lksctp-tools
  ros-groovy-orocos-kinematics-dynamics 
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtinyxml
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 249 not upgraded.3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/35.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 139 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 260756 files and directories currently installed.) 
Unpacking libtinyxml (from .../libtinyxml_2.6.2-2~ppa1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libtinyxml_2.6.2-2~ppa1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libtinyxml.so.2.6.2', which is also in package libtinyxml2.6.2 2.6.2-1build1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtinyxml_2.6.2-2~ppa1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then `apt-get install -y --reinstall libtinyxml libtinyxml-dev`:

```
root@nadirhajiyev:/home/nadirhajiyev# apt-get install -y libtinyxml libtinyxml-dev --reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  erlang-base erlang-crypto erlang-syntax-tools libqt4-webkit:i386 libsctp1 linux-headers-3.5.0-17 lksctp-tools
  ros-groovy-orocos-kinematics-dynamics
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtinyxml
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 249 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/35.4 kB of archives. 
After this operation, 139 kB of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for libtinyxml-dev:amd64
```

Finally I tried to remove it but I got:

```
root@nadirhajiyev:/home/nadirhajiyev# apt-get purge -y libtinyxml libtinyxml-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libtinyxml' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ros-groovy-nodelet : Depends: libtinyxml-dev but it is not going to be installed
  ros-groovy-pluginlib : Depends: libtinyxml-dev but it is not going to be installed
  ros-groovy-rospack : Depends: libtinyxml-dev but it is not going to be installed
  ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo : Depends: libtinyxml-dev but it is not going to be installed
  ros-groovy-srdf : Depends: libtinyxml-dev but it is not going to be installed
  ros-groovy-srdfdom : Depends: libtinyxml-dev but it is not going to be installed
  ros-groovy-urdfdom : Depends: libtinyxml-dev but it is not going to be installed
  ros-groovy-urdfdom-headers : Depends: libtinyxml-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve the problem. The problem was about broken dependencies. So first I built it again by `sudo apt-get build-dep` then I checked it by `sudo apt-get check`. It build broken dependencies and then I could successfully use `sudo apt-get upgrade` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your system is missing some dependencies and you should fix it.
Try to run this command sequence:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install -y && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it won't work and you'll still get this error message, try to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get -m upgrade
```

It will ignore missing packages, but may be a little risky.

Comment: I used both of them but did not help.

Comment: Try to run command: `sudo apt-cache search libtinyxml` to make sure that you have these in repos. If you do, try: `sudo apt-get install -y libtinyxml libtinyxml-dev`. If it won't help, try with parameter `--reinstall`. If it won't help too, then try to remove packages and install them again: `sudo apt-get purge -y libtinyxml libtinyxml-dev`.